# Permission Denied while running C programs in Windows

Tags: c, windows

I've installed Mingw (Tool that allows using GCC on Windows). GCC is working fine, it produces an executable. But I tried several attempts to run it, whithout success. Clicking or typing the program name in CMD produces an

```
Permission denied
```

error. Double clicking it as an Administrator pops up a cmd windows that soon closes without doing much.

Both ways, the executable file is deleted.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (){
    char word[300];
    scanf("%s", word);
    int ispalindrom = 1;

        for(int i = 0, j = strlen(word)-1; j>=i && ispalindrom; i++, j--){
            if(word[i] != word[j]){
                ispalindrom = 0;
            }
        }
    printf("%d", ispalindrom);
}
```

Is the program, it works fine on online compilers, I don't think the issue is there.

Comment: I know .c is not executable, mistyped. Mingw allows installing and using gcc on windows. gcc/mingw produces an executable.

Comment: Are you using some sort of antivirus?

Comment: Add a call to getchar() at the end of the code before the last closing brace } compile again and run it as administrator. Your  question is not very clear though.

Comment: Maybe, it's a new computer, may have something fabric-installed. I'll figure out and try it, thank you

Comment: @machine_1 Calling getchar() at the end made cmd open the executable file, thank you. The cmd popup lets me type the input, but as soon as i use enter the window closes without printing the result. At least, this time the executable file wasn't deleted this time

Comment: When it closes abruptly, it doesn't mean it is deleted. Try adding one more call to getchar() so that you have two calls, compile and run

Comment: @machine_1 for some reason it works on the git bash, thank you. What made you think that getchar() would solve the problem?

Comment: getchar() will hang the program until you press a key... After the program comes to an end, the cmd closes immediately. That doesn't happen if you invoke the program from cmd.

Comment: Invoking the program from the cmd (without) the getchar()  was causing a Permission Denied error. For some reason it solved the permission issue

Comment: On Windows 10, Defender will merrily forbid you from running your own programs, and cheerfully delete them too. Some of the many reasons why I deleted Windows 10 in favour of Windows 7.

Comment: @abcson, the console window is not CMD. Please take 10-15 minutes to read [about character mode applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/about-character-mode-applications);  20-30 minutes to read [about consoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/consoles); and 45-60 minutes to read about [using the console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-console), or at least spend a few minutes scanning it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that happens when you start the program but it's still running. At least that's what I concluded from my scenario testing thingy.

I looked around for a good explanation for why this happens but I could not find much. But I found some stuff [here](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/cs_edu/qt-creator/qt-creator-troubleshooting.shtml). (There's some stuff a quarter down)

You can try exiting the program with task manager. Or you can click on the link for more information.